# Why does my C++ cmd screen hang when I try to access a file to store data?

Tags: c++, error-handling

I have trying for hours to figure this out but I really dont understand what is wrong. When i try to create a teacher object tht goes into the file my visual studio gets stuck on the cmd screen and i can select any button to proceed.

this is my code. pls help me Im new to cpp:

```
    void populateActivityVector()
   {
    activity.clear();//for new data
    string temp = "";
    Activity tempActivity;
    ifstream inFile;
    try 
    {
        inFile.open("activity.txt", ios::in);
        while (!inFile.eof())
        {
            getline(inFile, temp);
            tempActivity.setID(temp);

            getline(inFile, temp);
            tempActivity.setName(temp);

            cout << temp << endl;
            activity.push_back(tempActivity);
        }
        inFile.close();
    }
    catch (std::ifstream::failure &readerr)
    {
        cout << "Reading Failed" << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < activity.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << activity[i].getID()<< endl;
    }
}

void main(){

    populateActivityVector();
    cout << "Succesfully complete!" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    system("pause");
}
```

it doesnt show the data from the file pls help me.

Comment: You are not checking a stream failure (only eof) - You may use `while(stream)` instead of `while (!inFile.eof())`

Comment: i tried checking if the file is even being read but it isnt even reading the file i dunno why...when i put the below code inside the while loop to test..it displays this but it never ends

cout << "hi" << endl;

Comment: The program may be trying to find the file in a different directory... or maybe the problem is somewhere else... Since you are using Visual Studio, have you tried debugging? Going line by line and inspecting the values under variables may help...

Comment: @Don "my visual studio gets stuck on the cmd screen and i can select any button to proceed".....what exactly do you expect `system("pause");` to do?

Comment: its not tht @Jeff what im trying to say is...the screen hangs and no matter what key you press..it doesnt close..like wen u use ..system("pause")

it shows a black screen with a blinking cursor

Comment: @Don ok, well in that case, where is the `"Activity.txt"` file located that you are trying to open.

Comment: the file is located in the directory where the project is stored. i created the textfile n input some values inside to test the function

Comment: Using a debugger, does execution get to the `for` loop afterwards?

Comment: You should print the number of iterations inside your `while` loop.

Comment: ok let me try n let you know the results

Answer (score 1):

"stuck on the cmd screen" before you press any key sounds like the result of

```
system("pause");
```

Comment: nope.it just hangs..i dunno why..i tried ion several pc n it gives the same result